# How can I find out the Scala supported SBT version

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, akka

I am migrating from Scala 2.10.5 to upgraded version of Scala 2.11.7, for that I changed `scalaVersion` in my `build.sbt`. Then I am facing `UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES` issue.

I gone through the one of similar issue. It suggests to use supported `SBT version`. How can I find out the supported SBT version for Scala 2.11.7?

Comment: What is exactly the error you're facing? What is this `UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES` you have?

Comment: And from which Scala version did you change?

Comment: you should really read the relevant section of the SBT docs on how managed dependency versions are resolved - http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Managed+Dependencies. And specifically this section which will help you understand why some of your dependencies cannot resolve currently due to changing the Scala version - http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Getting+the+right+Scala+version+with

Answer (score 0):

I did't find yet. But I find one blog that explained [**setup for Scala 2.11.7 project**](http://manuel.kiessling.net/2015/11/02/setting-up-an-sbt-based-project-for-scala-2-11-with-scalatest-support/) so he is using SBT 1.3.9. So by that reference. I also considering SBT 1.3.9 will work for Scala 2.11.7.

Anyway thanks for your reply.